# Generating the html file dynamically from the user inputs

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a requirement for my project . I want to generate html file dynamically from the user

inputs. I have searched a lot , but I couldn't find any links for this.Any help on this ?

Comment: Please elaborate.  What kind of input are you expecting?  How should the html file be like?

Comment: My input for Html will be string, I am trying to generate the html from the user input strings  ,and later convert it to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing. I think what you need to do is. create a template html page with container divs with id and load that file. On the delegate method of webview onPagefinishedloading run java script to add the information dynamically on the divs to the template html page.

Comment: can u please give some coding example

Answer (score 0):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self Class]];
NSString *htmlPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"html file name" ofType:@"htm"];
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//Do your HTML edits here

[[self webView] loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];
```